# MyBatis 3.5.6: Why isn't the IPage Interface Result Considered Too Many?

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-plus

[image]
[image]

I am using com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.mapper.BaseMapper#selectPage, but MyBatis considers that it returns too many results.

E selectPage(E page, @Param(Constants.WRAPPER) Wrapper queryWrapper);

org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.MethodSignature#MethodSignature

The boolean value for the judgment of returning many results is false. Why is it not true?

For example: Expected only one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 5223.